# Grammar Check - Missing Comma and Sentence Fragments not working

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've been troubleshooting an issue where Word (Office 2019, Office 2021 LSTC, and Office 365) isn't detecting missing commas or fragments. In Office 2019/2021 LTSC "Sentence Fragment" isn't an option. In Office 365 it is. In Office 2016 it works, no issue. I've made sure the appropriate boxes were checked and unchecked in the following places. :

Review > Language > Set Proofing Language > "Do Not check spelling or grammar"

File > Options > Proofing > Writing Styles: Grammar & Refinements > Settings > "Sentence Fragment" (I checked all the boxes as well in regards to commas and fragments lol)

File > Options > Proofing > "Hide spelling errors..." and "Hide grammar errors..." for both document options.

I used the following sentences for testing: "This this and this." and "Because it was raining."

I googled and can't seem to find anything or anyone else having an issue (I did find one MS post about office 365 but no solution). Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Thanks

Office Versions:

Office 365 - Version 2209 (Build 15629.20208)

Office 2021 - Version 2108 (Build 14332.20281 and 14332.202400)

Office 2016 - Version 16.0.5317.1000

Comment: I can confirm the problem in Word 365 and 2021. Fewer options in 2021. Send feedback directly to Microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/office/2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11 --  I have.